# How to point Google Cloud DNS to Plesk DNS

Tags: plesk, google-cloud-dns

I'm new at this, I have installed Plesk in a google compute engine without using the easiest way through marketplace.

My problem is with the DNS, to register my domain in [registro.br](https://registro.br/) it requires at least two different IPs, that Google DNS provides, but Plesk don't, so I'm copying manually all the DNSs from Plesk to Google, that takes a while, other problem is with renewing my SSLs automaticly, since my main DNS isn't from Plesk, it can't renew and I need to do that manually

Is there a way that I can use Google DNSs "NS" to register in registro.br, but manage it on Plesk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for Google Cloud DNS [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-forwarding). As you can see, you can set up DNS forwarding between your non-GCP name servers and Google Cloud's internal name servers, but it's possible only for [private zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_private_zones). Cloud DNS public managed zones do not support forwarding. [Public managed zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_public_zones) are only authoritative zones.

In my opinion, you should use Google Clous DNS as your primary DNS server and configure Plesk to use external DNS as it's shown in the [documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/72230/). To do this, use the custom type of installation (refer to the Deployment guide for details) and deselect the corresponding component (BIND DNS server support on Linux and Microsoft DNS server on Windows). In this case you cannot manage zones through Plesk. You can use external DNS server instead.

Unfortunately, there's no way to use Google Cloud DNS at registro.br and manage it on Plesk.

As an alternative, you can setup Plesk with DNS (BIND DNS server support on Linux and Microsoft DNS server on Windows) and then find DNS hosting and configure there secondary DNS for your domain (with different IP for registro.br). In this case, you don't need to use Google Cloud DNS at all, but you have to configure synchronization between your master and secondary DNS servers.