# Plesk Auto-renew letsencrypt using Google Cloud DNS

Tags: dns, plesk, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-dns

I have multiples domains on my plesk installed in a Google VM server, all of them has letsencrypt ssl installed, the problem is with my DNS.

I have to use Google Cloud DNS because I need two differents IPs to configure my domain on Registro.br

But using Google Cloud DNS, Plesk can't auto-renew my letsencrypt ssl and I need to update the wildcard key manually on Google Cloud DNS.

How can I force Plesk to update _acme-challenge TXT dns on Google Cloud DNS or point Google Cloud DNS to Plesk DNSs?

Comment: Please follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664766/12264548) provided by **Serhii Rohoza**.

Comment: @GagandeepT that solves my problem with copying all DNSs, but Plesk can't update an DNS record on Google Cloud DNS